# Save MTLTexture data locally in swift

Tags: swift, metal, metalkit

MTLTexture is a memory allocation for storing formatted image data that is accessible to the GPU.
I am curious if there is any way to to save MTLTexture data locally?

If so what would be the most suitable way to save MTLTexture data locally?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `getBytes` function to get image byte data from a texture:

```
getBytes(_:bytesPerRow:bytesPerImage:from:mipmapLevel:slice:)
```

> Copies a block of pixels from the storage allocation of a texture
>   slice into system memory at a specified address

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtltexture/1516318-getbytes

You can either use the bytes to create a `Data` object using:

```
Data.init(bytes: UnsafeRawPointer, count: Int)
```

Or you can use this data together with `CGCreateImage` to create an image. Full example here:

https://github.com/metal-by-example/sample-code/blob/master/objc/14-ImageProcessing/ImageProcessing/UIImage%2BMBETextureUtilities.m

Comment: Thanks oskar.I will go through

Comment: Are you looking to save it to a file, or keep a reference to an image whose backing storage is Metal-optimized? If you are doing the former, you can do what Oskar said and then use `Data.write(to: url)`. If you are doing the latter, you should use a `CVPixelBuffer` created with `kCVPixelBufferMetalCompatibilityKey` and then use `CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage` to get a texture that is bound to that pixel buffer's underlying memory. I can write an answer on that if desired.